# Error: Cannot retrieve the token. Timeout exceeded youtube authentication in nodejs youtube-video-api

Tags: node.js, google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth

Here's an inline link to https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-video-api
I am using nodejs youtube authentication and getting an error like

```
Can not authenticate Error: Cannot retrieve the token. Timeout exceeded
at Timeout._onTimeout (/opt/lampp/htdocs/mastermind/node_modules/nightmare-google-oauth2/index.js:179:18)
at ontimeout (timers.js:469:11)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:304:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:264:5)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a known issue in the library you are using.

See: [[Error: Cannot retrieve the token. Timeout exceeded]](https://github.com/h2non/google-oauth2-token/issues/5)

> It might be possible that Google changed (again) the login process, so automated web interaction is not possible anymore. I'm not using this package these days anymore, but I used to modify it multiple times in the past every couple of months because Google changed the login forms, so automation should be manually adapted every time.

You may want to comment on the projects github page.